# NodeJs: Whenever checkbox is checked I wanted them to be added to my VerificationData setter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need help on how to add data on my array whenever one/or many of them are checked.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

{
    verifications.map(record => {
        console.log(verifications)
        return(
            <Col xs={12} md={3} mb={3}>
                <Form.Group key={record.id} className="mb-3" controlId={record.verifyName}>
                      <Form.Check value={record.verifyName} label={record.verifyName} />
                  </Form.Group>
            </Col>  

            )
    })
}
```

Example:
• First Name
• Last Name
• Address

If I checked on first name and address, they will be added to my state setter for data.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: how is this node.js?

Comment: Not a nodejs my apologies it should be nextjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an onChange event inside the check input and call setData function to set value. Here an example

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data);
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value="Rahul"
        name="firstName"
        onChange={e => setData([...data, e.target.value])}
      />
    </div>
```

Comment: It's not working for me. I am getting the value in JS but not in NodeJs. I have tried to get the tag name as well but it's not working maybe because JS is different from NodeJs.

Comment: This is you front end right? You have backend developed with NodeJS?

Comment: I do both. This is just for the frontend. What I wanted to do is just stored them in my data array as I will call them once the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

What works at the moment is this:

```
<Form.Group
key={record.id} 
className="mb-3" 
controlId={record.verifyName}>

<Form.Check onChange={e=>{
    const value = e.target.value
    collection.push(value);
    console.log(collection)}}
    tag="verify"
    value={record.verifyName} 
    label={record.verifyName} />

</Form.Group>
```

However, whenever the value is clicked multiple times, it keeps on adding. I've tried to add a conditional statement but doesn't do anything not sure if it's correct.

```
if(value.checked == true) {
collection.push(value)
}
```

I guess the reason was because I'm targetting it's value not the object? Any help?